# Аргументы функции в xml android:onClick

Tags: android, android-xml

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать аргументы в функцию?

Так нельзя:

`<Button
     android:onClick="qwe(1, 2, 3)"
     ... />`

Comment: А смысл писать их в `xml`? Метод будет каждый раз вызываться с одними и теми же значениями аргументов - что тогда мешает вписать их прямо в код метода. Вообще писать какие-то куски кода в `xml` возможно с библиотекой [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) - но её использование требует дополнительного изучения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя. В xml вы можете укзать метод, и будет сгенерирован View.OnClickListener, в котором этот метод вызывается. Если у метода есть параметр типа View - в него передастся View из View.OnClickListener, все остальные параметры не допускаются.

Как действовать, если вы хотите вызывать одну функцию при нажатии на разные элементы:
все элементы должны иметь разный id(если вы их в большом количестве инфлейтите программно, можно задавать tag и использовать его вместо id). Всем вешаем ваш метод в onClick. Внутри onClick получаем в параметрах View, это тот самый элемент, на который на который нажали. Получаем сравниваем view.getId() с нашими значениями через switch/if, делаем что должно. В теории вам хватит одного слушателя на все нажимабельные элементы, но это малочитаемо и неудобно, как правило.

Ну и на последок. Забудьте про атрибут android:onClick. Это описание поведения там, где описывается разметка, это очень плохой подход. А еще оно генерит такой "красивый" код, что просто диву даешься... Реализуйте onClickListener в коде и передавайте его нужным элементам. Это не сильно раздует ваш код, зато избавит от бессмысленной рефлексии и неопределенностей

Answer (score 2):

Из разметки вы можете вызвать только стандартный метод `onClick(View)`, соответственно если у вас этот метод вызывается несколькими кнопками, то используйте либо `if` либо `switch case`, в них проверяйте `id` конкретной кнопки, и передавайте нужные переменные.